# Magento: Set items out of stock if not using inventory - how?

Tags: magento

My client doesn't need to use the inventory management system in Magento; and instead just wants to do it manually. How can she simply set a product to out of stock ? I know we could just disable the product but we want to have the product show in the category and search (as inactive or something eg with the buy button disabled) so that the customer knows it is normally stocked and can try again later or bookmark the page etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No programming needed.  Just go to

```
Catalog -> Manage Products -> PRODUCT -> Inventory
```

and set `Stock Availability` to *Out of Stock*.

Comment: thanks but having set system>config>inventory>manage stock to "no" this option is now gone

Comment: Well, then turn it back on, set your stock levels in the millions, and be done with it.

Comment: thanks alan, but this wont work for me. My client has a large number of products i dont think she'd accept it (she'd doing the stocking herself ) typing in a 6 digit number into a field every time is ??? - and of course there's the worry of missing that field and having a product permanently out of stock. I am very surprised that magento hasnt a soloution. I was looking at the section System>configuration> inventory>stock options>Decrease Stock When Order is Placed. Do you know whether this works properly ( i'm just suspicious why no one mentions it ) ... at least that would be slightly better

Comment: You don't have to turn on stock management for all products in the configuration. You can leave it off and just turn it on for that one specific product.

Comment: thank you - i missed this completely - i didnt realise the tickbox allowed you to to override the global setting - i suppose it's not 100% obvious so for anyone who misses it, it's just a case of turning off the global inventory ( which effectively sets all products to in stock) and then on a per product basis you can untick the checkbox under inventory, turn on stock management and then set the product to out of stock .... thanks again Anders